# How do I share data between apps using internal storage and SharedUserID on Android with React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

So I'm currently developing a suite of apps with the intention of being able to sign in on of them and be logged in on all of them. I read I could give them all a common SharedUserID in their respective app manifests and then they'd be able to access each other's data. However, the SharedUserID seems to make no difference; I just get a file not found error when I try to access data saved from another app.

Should I expect internal storage to just be shared between the apps by default or do I need to specifically navigate to some kind of "shared folder" when reading/writing?

Most of the material I've read about shared user IDs has been from people developing specifically for Android, but I'm developing native modules under react native and I'm not sure if that will have an effect or not. Has anyone tried anything like this?

Note: These apps are being developed from scratch, I'm **NOT** trying to add a sharedUserId to an existing app.

Comment: "So I'm currently developing a suite of apps with the intention of being able to sign in on of them and be logged in on all of them" -- single-sign-on would not require `sharedUserId` -- use IPC (broadcasts, bound services, etc.) and `signature` permissions to securely communicate between apps.

Comment: @commonsware could you elaborate?

Comment: @EHorodyski: Not without context. There are very few problems in this world for which `sharedUserId` is a better solution than having apps communicate with each other using IPC. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you explain your problem.

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean by IPC, especially in a hybrid-mobile world. I'm looking for a similar solution on the other spectrum of hybrid-mobile apps, but it all boils down to the same issue, SSO between mobile apps.